# DataGrid populated using ItemsSource not sortable despite CanUserSortColumns="true"

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid

I have a datagrid populated from a database so I can view and make changes to the database.

However, you can't sort the columns by clicking on the header. When you click on them nothing happens. I've seen lots of questions on S.O. like this, and I've changed my XMAL lots and tried different things but no answers seem to have fixed this for me.

Here's my C#.

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadDataGrid();
    }

    private void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        TasksDataContext tasksDB = new TasksDataContext();
        var tasks = (from p in tasksDB.LubeTasks select p);
        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = tasks;
    }
```

Here's the XMAL I first tried from a tutorial:

```
    <grid:DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="True">
        <grid:DataGrid.Columns>

            <grid:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}"
                                Header="Number" CanUserSort="True" />


            <grid:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Description}"
                                Header="Description" CanUserSort="True"/>

        </grid:DataGrid.Columns>
    </grid:DataGrid>
```

I also tried adding things like `SortMemberPath="Number.code"` or `SortMemberPath="Number"` and monkeying around with different tags, but it still won't sort.

I also tried a structure like this going off another tutorial [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?775605-WPF-DataGrid-Sortable-Column-Header), but it also doesn't work.

```
    <grid:DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <grid:DataGrid.Columns>


                <grid:DataGridTemplateColumn  SortMemberPath="Number" CanUserSort="true">
                    <grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Number"/>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </grid:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <grid:DataGridTemplateColumn  SortMemberPath="Description" CanUserSort="true">
                    <grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Description" />
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </grid:DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </grid:DataGrid.Columns>
    </grid:DataGrid>
```

Is the problem with how I populate the datagrid? I've tried using `MyDataGrid.DataContext = tasks;` but if I do that I can't seem to get the datagrid filled in at all.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: did you set  SortMemberPath ?

Comment: Yes, in the first example I tried `<grid:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" SortMemberPath="Number" CanUserSort="True"` and it had no effect. Should I put a SortMemberPath in the `DataGrid` tag? In the second example you can see the SortMemberPaths.

Comment: Use CollectionViewSource. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your LINQ result from Database in a struct that supports sorting.

Try this:

```
    TasksDataContext tasksDB = new TasksDataContext();
    var tasks = (from p in tasksDB.LubeTasks select p).ToList();
    MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = tasks;
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you. Though you might want to edit it to `ToList()`

Comment: Ah damn, this messes up my editing though. Now I get the error `sorting' is not allowed during an addnew or edititem transaction`.

Comment: It was a bit finicky. If you update from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5, you don't actually need to add the `ToList()`. But in 4.5, it throws a `'sorting' is not allowed during an addnew or edititem transaction` when you edit something. If you use 3.5 and add the `ToList()` that seems to work though.